# Accessing Input element inside <ion-input />

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework

For a personal project I try to create a JS app using vueJS and Ionic. I want to use the google.maps.places API, and to make this API works, I need to provide to the autocomplete object the input in which my users will enter the street they are looking for.

To do so, I created this vueJS component (CustomInput.vue):

```
<template>
  <ion-input v-bind="$attrs" class="custom-input"/>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { IonInput } from '@ionic/vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'CustomInput',
  components: { IonInput },
});
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
ion-input.sportlink-input {
  --background: #f1f5f9;
  --padding-start: 1rem;
  --padding-end: 1rem;
  --padding-top: 0.75rem;
  --padding-bottom: 0.75rem;
  --placeholder-color: #64748b;

  border-radius: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid #f1f5f9;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;

  &.has-focus {
    border-color: var(--ion-color-primary);
  }
}
</style>
```

Then I create an InputLabel that includes a CustomInput, (InputLabel.vue) :

```
<template>
  <ion-item lines="none" class="custom-item" :class="error && 'ion-invalid'">
    <ion-label v-if="label" position="stacked" class="custom-label">{{ label }}</ion-label>
    <custom-input v-bind="$attrs" v-model="valueProxy" :placeholder="placeholder" :type="type"  ref="ionInputRef"/>
    <ion-note slot="error">{{ error }}</ion-note>
  </ion-item>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {computed, defineComponent, onMounted, ref, toRefs, defineExpose} from 'vue';
import customInput from '@/components/ionicWrappers/customInput.vue';
import {IonLabel, IonItem, IonNote, IonInput} from '@ionic/vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'InputLabel',
  components: {IonInput, IonLabel, customInput, IonItem, IonNote },
  props: {
    label: {
      type: String,
    },
    type: String,
    placeholder: String,
    modelValue: {
      type: [String, Number],
    },
    error: String,
  },
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const { modelValue } = toRefs(props);
    const ionInputRef = ref(null);

    // defineExpose({ ionInputRef })

    onMounted(() => {
      // Make ionInputRef available for external access
      emit('ionInputRef', ionInputRef.value);
    });

    const valueProxy = computed({
      get() {
        return modelValue.value;
      },
      set(value) {
        emit('update:modelValue', value);
      },
    });
    return { valueProxy };
  },
});
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
</style>
```

Finally When I want to use it I use it like this (any parent that need the input):

```
<v-field v-slot="{ field, errors }" as="" name="street" :rules="validationSchema.name">
    <input-label v-bind="field" type="text" :label="$t('createEvent.endDate')" :error="errors[0]" @ionInputRef="onIonInputRef" ref="streetRef" />
</v-field>
```

I try to get the input like this : (any parent Inside Setup()):

```
    const onIonInputRef = (r) => {
        nextTick(() => {
          console.log("onIonInputRef", r);
          console.log("onIonInputRef element", r.$el)
          console.log("onIonInputRef element input", r.$el.querySelector('input'))

          ionInputRef.value = r

          const inputElement = ionInputRef.value;
          console.log("inputElement", inputElement.$el);
          const inputElementByName = document.getElementsByName('street')[1];
          console.log("inputElementByName", inputElementByName);
          console.log("inputElement", inputElement.$el);
          console.log("ion children", inputElement.$el.children);
          console.log("ion children[0]", inputElement.$el.children[0]);
          console.log("length of ion children", inputElement.$el.children.length);
          console.log("ionInput", ionInputRef.value.$el.querySelector('input'));
          const shadowRoot = ionInputRef.value.$el.shadowRoot;
          console.log("shadowRoot", shadowRoot)
          if (shadowRoot) {
            inputElement.value = shadowRoot.querySelector('input');
            console.log("shadowRoot", shadowRoot);
            console.log("inputElement", inputElement);
          }

          // if (inputElement) {
          //   // Now you have access to the HTML input element
          //   console.log("inputElement", inputElement);
          //   autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputElement, {
          //     types: ['address'],
          //     fields: ['address_components'],
          //   });
          //
          //   google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {
          //     console.log('place changed');
          //     console.log(autocomplete.getPlace());
          //   });
          // }
        });
      // }
    };
```

These console.log print these values :
[image]

It seem that when accessing the reference using the `$el` property, it returns me the ion-input component, but what I really want is the  inside the . When accessing it, the component is `undefined` or `null`.

Do you have any idea on how I can access the  component ?

Comment: If I understood what you are trying to do, you would need to set a ref attribute in your CustomInput.vue component for you to access its input element, like so: this.$el.streetRef.$el.ionInputRef.$el.inputElementRef. This should give you the DOM HTMLElement object for the input.